# ckeditor textarea output as html tags in browser. I am using laravel 5.2 and mysql database. How to fix this issue?

Tags: ckeditor, laravel-5, ckeditor5

I want to get the textarea data and show in browser. I am using CKEditor with textarea. But textarea data show with html tags as output.

In the editor I write "This is textarea" but it displays as `<p>This is text textarea</p>` in browser.

Trying to set up configuration of ckeditor config.js file from the documentation with `'config.htmlEncodeOutput = true'` and `'config.basicEntities = false'`. But it doesn't work.

```
<textarea name="post_description" id="editor" cols="30" rows="15" class="form-control"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to properly escape strings that contain HTML tags so that they are formatted by browser engine. In Laravel you can simply change where you display your content from:

```
{{ $text }}
```

to

```
{!! $text !!}
```